# Issue with Pagespeed: "Properly defines charset Error"

Tags: pagespeed-insights, hubspot

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on a project hosted on HubSpot, and I've encountered an issue with Pagespeed Insights. The tool is flagging a "Properly defines charset Error," even though I have correctly specified the  tag in my HTML.

As a result, the "best practice" indicator is marked in red, and no value is displayed. I've double-checked the charset declaration, and it seems accurate. Has anyone else experienced a similar problem with Pagespeed Insights on HubSpot? Are there any known solutions or workarounds to address this issue and get the "best practice" indicator to display the correct values?

Your insights and suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I've double-checked the charset declaration, and it seems accurate.

Comment: It would help if you told us what charset you are using and where in the HTML it is (it should be one of the first things declared in the `<head>`)

Comment: i am using  <meta charset="utf-8"> and it declared first as you mentioned

Comment: Not sure what's happening. If you can share the URL or recreate a minimal test case in glitch.com or something that also fails then might be able to help further.

Comment: https://leverx.com/ - this site gives error Properly defines charset Error in https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-leverx-com/d6l1tthjaf?form_factor=desktop Pagespeed Insights tests

Answer (score 1):

PageSpeed Insights (PSI) was not complaining the charset wasn't there.

It was complaining an error occurred and it was unable to check:

[image: Screenshot of PSI showing the error]

As you can see the actual error is "Required MainDocumentContent gatherer encountered an error: Protocol error (Network.getResponseBody): Request content was evicted from inspector cache".

It looks like the issue was apparently [fixed recently in Lighthouse](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/10876) and should be in version v11.1.0. PSI is currently on v11.0.0 so that explains why it's still showign there. However when I test locally in DevTools (on 11.3.0) I still see the same error. So I [commented on that bug](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/10876#issuecomment-1858335946).

In the meantime you can ignore this error as the charset is indeed correct.